Computing Value of Discontinuity in Signal x(t)
Assume we have the following graph of a discontinuous signal x(t):

What's the procedure to compute the value of discontinuity in x(t) at t = 2?

The value is undefined. You can't compute it using a "standard process"

In the textbook "Signals & Systems, A. Oppenheim", it says "Note, for example, that the discontinuity in x(t) at t = 2 has a value of -3" (Example 1.7, page 37)

If you have a jump discontinuity at some $t=t_0$ as in the given example, the value $x(t_0)$ is undefined. You only have a left-sided limit $x(t_0^-)$ and a right-sided limit $x(t_0^+)$.
What is probably meant here is that when you differentiate the signal, the area of the resulting Dirac delta impulses is given by the difference of the one-sided limits. I.e., the (generalized) derivative of the given signal is
$$x'(t)=2\delta(t-1)-3\delta(t-2)+2\delta(t-4)\tag{1}$$
where the multipliers in $(1)$ are given by the differences of the respective one-sided limits. Calling these differences "values of discontinuities" is a bit confusing.

Thanks a lot for the help and clarifications.

@Habib-MbarkaAmmari: If this answered your question, you can click on the green checkmark to accept this answer, thanks!
